# Inverse Kinematics Armature Rotation

Tags: animation, armature, inverse-kinematics

When trying to learn how to animate characters today I wanted to accomplish learning Inverse Kinematics. Watched a couple tutorials on youtube, seems pretty straight forward. When I apply the target bone in the IK Constraints my character and armature rotates forward slightly like hes drunk and about to fall over. On all the videos I watched none of the characters or armature move unless the armature itself is moved. Literally the second I add the target bone it rotates forward. So what I did was duplicate the foot / shin, made the shin the pole and the foot the target. Cleared the parents and made sure the bones aren't set to deform. My guess is I either accidentally did something to the armature or it has an existing problem. What could be causing this?[image]

Comment: check if your chain length is correct, 0 seems like the issue.